# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on google.com resource

Tags: networking, google-api-client

This is a weird thing that is happening to one of our users. Using chrome browser they sometimes get a ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED from google. I have never seen this before, looks as a kind of DoS attack mitigation.

Does somebody has been getting similar errors and some hints or ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked their extensions? Some ad-blockers force close connections if they think the domain is serving ads. This could be a false positive.

Comment: thanks. Nop, but it's a  google.com ?

Comment: Google serves ads from time to time ;) Just try and disable extensions one-by-one to find the culprit.